# Reinstalling NuGet packages with NuGet installed as VS Extension

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to be able to install all of the NuGet packages in the packages.config, as per [The NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages). NuGet is installed as a VS Extension, and I can't seem to find nuget.exe. Is it possible to run:

> nuget i packages.config -o Packages

Without maintaining a seperate copy of nuget.exe on a per project basis?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As an update to this post, NuGet 1.6 added support for the workflow to restore the packages at build time if missing. 
Right-Click on the solution, click "Enable Package Restore Mode" to set it on.

More details at:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Answer (score 82):

Reinstall all packages in all projects of the current solution:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

You can find more information about reinstalling nuget packages **[here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages)**

Comment: This command also updates all packages to newer versions, doesn't it?

Comment: Don't, this just reinstall!

Comment: It updates when there is no old version available on nuget.org.

Answer (score 22):

**Warning** - using

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

or

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies
```

may remove all of your packages and package.config files!

Always make sure that you have your backups performed first.

**Scenario**:

- Solution with multiple projects
- Each contains their own Nuget entries, some with the same packages (e.g., SharpRepository, Entity Framework)
- Now copy folder without the packages folder for "distribution" somewhere else
- Assume the packages folder wasn't included with the distribution
- Now try the command `Update-Package -Reinstall` or if you have some alpha packages and/or are sure your dependencies are good, try `Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies`

**Result**:
Because the packages folder doesn't exist,  the entries for your packages methodically go away, too. This can surprise some people - so be careful, is all I'm saying.

Comment: the second one worked after getting an error "the type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace"

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution on [This blog entry](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/04/12/nuget-and-projects-under-source-control.aspx). I needed to install [NuGet.CommandLine](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/NuGet.CommandLine), which makes nuget.exe. globally available in the VS command line. I can then set this up as a pre-build event to ensure that dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: Even better solution http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: You don't need any pre-build events, you can 'Enable NuGet package restore' and it will integrate NuGet with your build. Note that when you do this, a .nuget folder is creates that you need to commit to version control. The .nuget folder contains a copy of nuget.exe - if you don't want to commit that file, there is a tweak you can make in the nuget.targets file that will make it download nuget.exe as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier option that you can keep enabled in Visual Studio during development to ease off your NuGet package installation related pain.

Keep both below mentioned options under `NuGet Package Manager` > `General` in checked state -

1. Allow NuGet to download missing packages
2. Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio

Have a look at the screenshot below:

[image]